# react-native SectionList can not scrollToLocation when i was scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I want to implement a component similar to address book, but SectionList can jump normally when clicking on the letter on the right when there is no scroll. But when it's scrolling (and the inertia isn't over), clicking on the right letter doesn't jump

react-native :0.58.6
react:16.8.3

```
 <SectionList
                ref="sectionList"
                renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
                getItemLayout={this.itemLayout}
                sections={this.props.dataList}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index)=> String(index)}
                onScrollBeginDrag={(event)=>{
                    this.refs.letterspace.changeActive()
                }}
                refreshing={this.props.isRefreshing}
            />
```

Clicking on the right letter triggers the following function

```
getIndex = (index) => {
        let rollIndex = index
        // console.log(rollIndex,'rollindex')
        this.refs.sectionList.scrollToLocation({animated: false, itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: rollIndex})
    }
```

Comment: When the list is scrolling, no event occurs?

Comment: @hongdevelop  That's when I scroll through the list with my finger, and it's not done yet

Comment: Are you saying that you can't refresh even if you scroll?

Comment: @hongdevelop no,I mean, it doesn't work to trigger a function scrollToLocation  when the scrolling isn't finished

Comment: were you able to solve this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You likely need `forwardRef`.  Here's an example of a component that provides a section list.  Note the final export is the one with `forwardRef`

```
import React, { ForwardedRef, forwardRef, PropsWithRef } from 'react';
import { SectionList, SectionListData, SectionListProps } from 'react-native';

export type SectionScrollViewProps = PropsWithRef<
  Omit<SectionListProps<any>, 'sections' | 'renderItem'> & {
    children: JSX.Element[];
  }
>;
function SectionScrollViewWithRef(
  { children, ...props }: SectionScrollViewProps,
  ref: ForwardedRef<SectionList<JSX.Element>>
): JSX.Element {
  function renderItem({ item }: { item: JSX.Element }): JSX.Element {
    return item;
  }
  const sectionListSections: SectionListData<JSX.Element>[] = children.map((child) => ({
    data: [child],
  }));
  return (
    <SectionList ref={ref} sections={sectionListSections} renderItem={renderItem} {...props} />
  );
}
export const SectionScrollView = forwardRef(SectionScrollViewWithRef);
```

Here's an example on how to use it

```
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { createRef } from "react";
import { Button, SectionList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SectionScrollView } from "./SectionScrollView";

export function ScrollSectionViewScreen() {
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  const scrollViewRef = createRef<SectionList>();
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button
        color={colors.primary}
        onPress={() => {
          scrollViewRef.current?.scrollToLocation({
            sectionIndex: 0,
            itemIndex: 0,
          });
        }}
        title="0"
      />
      <Button
        color={colors.primary}
        onPress={() => {
          scrollViewRef.current?.scrollToLocation({
            sectionIndex: 1,
            itemIndex: 0,
          });
        }}
        title="1"
      />
      <Button
        color={colors.primary}
        onPress={() => {
          scrollViewRef.current?.scrollToLocation({
            sectionIndex: 5,
            itemIndex: 0,
          });
        }}
        title="5"
      />
      <SectionScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: "yellow", borderWidth: 10 }}
      >
        <View
          key="0"
          style={{
            borderColor: colors.border,
            borderWidth: 10,
            minHeight: 300,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Section 0</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          key="1"
          style={{
            borderColor: colors.border,
            borderWidth: 10,
            minHeight: 300,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Section 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          key="2"
          style={{
            borderColor: colors.border,
            borderWidth: 10,
            minHeight: 300,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Section 2</Text>
        </View>
        <Text key="2" style={{ color: colors.text }}>
          Section 2
        </Text>
        <Text key="3" style={{ color: colors.text }}>
          Section 3
        </Text>
        <Text key="4" style={{ color: colors.text }}>
          Section 4
        </Text>
        <View
          key="5"
          style={{
            borderColor: colors.border,
            borderWidth: 10,
            minHeight: 600,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Section 5</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          key="6"
          style={{
            borderColor: colors.border,
            borderWidth: 10,
            minHeight: 600,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Section 6</Text>
        </View>
      </SectionScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```